# Passing reference from C++-CLI to C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll, reference, c++-cli

I'm trying to pass a ref of type ITestObject from a method in C++ to C# and there accessing data inside the reference. C# and CPP gets type-def from same DLL (Test.dll) C++ receives the ref from outside and I can access all data inside. The compile error is:

> error C2664: Can not convert parameter 1 from 'ITestObject *' to 'Test::ITestObject ^%'.

#### C++/CLI

```
// Test.dll contains implementation of ITestObject
#import "C:\Program Files\T\Test.dll" no_namespace

double __clrcall Calc(ITestObject* tObj)
{
    return TS::ClassA::Calc((System::IntPtr)tObj, _2);
}
```

#### C# DLL

```
using Test;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CLib 
{
    public Class classA 
    {
       public static double Calc(IntPtr tRef)
        {
          IntPtr pInterface;
          ITestObject myObj;
          IntPtr ptr = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(tRef); // Generate the IntPtr

          // Retrieving ITestObject
          // Version 1
          IntPtr pIUnk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(tRef);
          Int32 result = Marshal.QueryInterface(pIUnk, ref myGuid, out pInterface);
          myObj = ??              

          // Version 2 
          IntPtr pIUnk2 = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(tRef, typeof(ITestObject));
          // vTable = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pIUnk2); <-- necessary?
          myObj = (ITestObject) Convert.ChangeType(pIUnk2, typeof(ITestObject));
          Marshal.Release(pIUnk);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage of const as proposed by MS doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try to remove the ref from the C# method?

Comment: Is `ITestObject` a COM interface?

Comment: Marshall and or wrap the C++ object which is no (!) C++/cli object

Comment: ITestObject* is an *unmanaged* COM interface pointer, it cannot be used directly in C# code.  There's just no need for it, C# can use interop with COM by itself without you having to help.  Simple use Project + Add Reference, Browse tab, select C:\Program Files\T\Test.dll

Comment: Removing ref I've tried plus many more variants. ITestObject in Test.dll is an Interop-DLL (most likely C++) and used from my C++ and C#. @Hans That is what I did, added the Lib as reference in my C#-Project. I need my C++-DLL because I'm programming inside another unmanaged app, so calling C# directly doesn't work.

Comment: The ITestObject type in your C# program is a *managed* type, it was created by Tlbimp.exe or by adding the reference to the type library.  It has the same name as the native COM interface type but is *not* the same as the native ITestObject type used in your C++/CLI code.  The best you could do is declare Calc(IntPtr tObj), cast it to IUnknown and call its QueryInterface() method to get the native ITestObject* pointer back.  You need Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject() in the C# code to generate the IntPtr.

Comment: Ok, sounds very promising but I couldn't figure out how to proceed on c++ and c# side. My c# signature is changed (see original question) and on c++ I assume no change is needed.

Comment: On MS and here on other questions I've read about the suggested things from Hans but the more I read about it the more it puzzled me. To pass the ref from C++ to C# I'm using IntPtr but retrieving the interface in C# will not work for me. Some ideas I've got from a similar question here with example of IDirectSound and answers from @Hans. I've updated the code above with two variants retrieving the interface but something is wrong/missing. Thx for any help.